# Pressing delete on a white (blank) line in a List Box in C# Winforms

Tags: c#, string, listbox

At the moment I have a list box which shows a title and then leaves a blank space.
I allow my users to delete entries into the list box whilst using the application but I cant seem to prevent the deleteItem dialog from running when they click on a white (blank line)

I have tried:

```
this.listBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == ("")

this.listBox.SelectedItem.ToString().Equals("")
```

&

```
this.listBox.SelectedItem.ToString().Length == 0
```

Neither of these seem to want to work.

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: And what's in the SelectedItem at the moment you compare it with an empty string?

Comment: At the moment, when the program UI loads and the user saves their first entry to the listbox i place a title

listBox.add("Title");
I then follow this by entering a blank line
listBox.add("");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var selected = listBox.SelectedItem;
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(selected.ToString()))
{
    //Remove it
    listBox.Items.Remove(selected);
}
```

Comment: Technically this removes the **first** entry found in the ListBox that is "blank".  If there is only ever **one** blank line, then great; otherwise use [ListBox.SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx) and [ListBox.Items.RemoveAt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.removeat(v=vs.110).aspx) to remove the one that is actually selected by the user when the delete button was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Answered with thanks to User:Emile Pels

```
var selected = listBox.SelectedItem;
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(selected.ToString()))
{
    //Remove it
    listBox.Items.Remove(selected);
}
```

I used the 'String''s `IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` method from the answer to check for the blank line in the List Box.

Thank you